# What is the difference between shirt and shirts?

Tags: grammar

Please, tell me the difference between shirt and shirts.
I didn't find the meaning of the difference on the web.
Would you give me the answer?

Comment: Please don't just say, "I didn't find the difference on the web." At least tell us where you searched and what you found.

Comment: I see how your confusion/question arose. In Korean, they call a “shirt,” plural or not, “셔츠,” which is a transliteration for “shirts.” The OP must have mistaken “shirts” as a plurale tantum.

Answer (score 3):

Shirt is the singular form and indicates "one". The other refers to the plural form, indicating "more than one". The same for T-shirt/T-shirts.